# AngularJSJ - Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] (chrome console error)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

I have done some research on the error I am getting but nothing has worked. The error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=MemberModule&p1=Re…%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fjavascripts%2FMemberModule.js%3...<omitted>...5)
```

Here is my code:

index.jade:

```
doctype html
html(ng-app="MemberModule")
  head
    title= title

    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/javascripts/vendor/bootstrap-css/css/bootstrap.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')

    script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js")
    script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js')
    script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/vendor/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js')
    script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js')
    script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/MemberModule.js')

    #heady

  block head

  body
    block content
```

As you can see - I think I am loading all the scripts in the correct order.

MemberModule.js:

```
var MemberModule = angular.module('MemberModule', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute']);

MemberModule.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $routeProvider
    .when('/member/:id.json', {
      templateUrl: '/templates/home.jade',
      controller: MemberListCtrl
  });
});

MemberModule.controller('MemberListCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
  function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
  }
]);
```

I'm guessing its something in MemberModule.js. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

This is what firefox console says - a little more info, looks like something isn't defined:

```
[12:34:55.413] Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=MemberModule&p1=MemberListCtrl%20is%20not%20defined%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fjavascripts%2FMemberModule.js%3A9%0Ad%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A33%0Ae%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A32%0Ar%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%0Ae%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A32%0AZb%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A35%0AYb%2Fc%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%0AYb%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%0AUc%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%0A%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A206%0Aa%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A138%0Aie%2Fc%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A30%0Ar%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%0Aie%2Fc%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A30%0A @ https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:6
```

**UPDATE**

Instead of using Google CDN, I downloaded the scripts and put them in the site directory - no more dependency errors - but I do have an error that I'm not sure of (if anyone can help):

```
[12:42:14.899] ReferenceError: MemberListCtrl is not defined @ http://localhost:3000/javascripts/MemberModule.js:9
```

I updated my MemberModule.js to reflect what it looks like now.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting an undefined error is because it's not defined within the scope of the function trying to use it. Just because you registered an object with that name with Angular doesn't mean that the config function has it. You will need to either inject that controller or specify the controller in the template (my personal preference).

Comment: thanks! this is what i did: var MemberModule = angular.module('MemberModule', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute', 'MemberListCtrl']); - now im getting No module MemberListCtrl - i have it defined though - probably still a scope problem that im not understanding - dont want to add controller to the template because I am in beginning phases and nothing actually happens in the template i want to load - it just says "p Here" for testing purposes.

Comment: You're injecting it in the wrong place. When you call angular.module() you're defining your application module. You then use that module to build and register things in your application. The things that you inject inside that module call are other modules that yours depends on. You want to inject the controller into the MemberModule.config function, which is where you're referencing the controller.

Comment: Even if the controller's not doing anything, you can still reference it using the ng-controller directive inside your template... this will automatically load the controller, looking inside your module for registered controllers. It will scale a lot better than defining it in your config method.

Comment: great - ill give it a shot - one sec

Comment: ok - another error - i added ng-controller to template - and this is what i did to config block - MemberModule.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, MemberListCtrl) - error is: [13:07:29.605] Error: Unknown provider: MemberListCtrl from MemberModule @ http://localhost:3000/javascripts/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:29

Comment: Try moving the call to MemberModule.controller up above the call to MemberModule.config

Comment: And if you've moved it into the template, you can remove the reference to MemberListCtrl from the config method completely, including not specifying it in the .when on your $routeProvider (just use the template)

Comment: ok - i removed the injection - i put the ng-controller reference in the template that IS TO BE LOADED (home.jade) not the index template (index.jade) like this - block content
 div.container(ng-controller="MemberListCtrl")
  p Here - is this right? or does it need to be in index.jade? also - still have error - [13:15:34.768] ReferenceError: MemberListCtrl is not defined @ http://localhost:3000/javascripts/MemberModule.js:14

Comment: I have to run off to a meeting. Can you put up a plunkr? After you do that, I'll open up a chat window with you when I get back and we can avoid having an epic discussion in comments.

Comment: great sounds good - will do - i realized you meant remove the reference to controller in config block...not the injection - so i just did that - gonna see what happens - do i need the injection if i have the reference in my jade file? ill make a plunker

Comment: plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/8xW5r82CXetC90TwjRv9?p=preview - I don't think I did it right though - don't use plunker very often - might need a little help getting it to work so u can help. thanks man!

Comment: can i just create all the files in my directory on the plunker sight and it will work?

Comment: second attempt at plunker - saw there is an angular template - still not working how my site works though - http://plnkr.co/edit/VGtOnb7Qz502MAUtvdtm?p=preview - look forward to chatting after your meeting

Comment: i also have something to do at 3 pm est - but if you arent able to help by then - i would appreciate chatting some other time - thanks!

Comment: I don't know if this solves everything, but on the plunkr you were missing ng-app on the html tag, as fixed here:http://plnkr.co/edit/HM3c714vv7xt1ZEMEqMH?p=preview

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51369/discussion-between-jsager-and-ewizard)